# Permalink Settings: optional settings doesn’t apply to editor

Tags: posts, categories, permalinks

In my WordPress 3.8 in my "Permalink Settings" I've chosen the option "Post name". Then I've added "Optional" for "Category" ( `%category%/%postname%` ), the URLs works like I wanted - `http://example.com/categoryname/postname` - however this rule doesn’t apply to the editor - when I create new post or edit the existing post the URL in editor is still `http://example.com/postname`, so when I click on *View Post* or *Preview Changes* it redirects me to this wrong URL which shows Page Not Found.

Any help/ideas? what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to select the option `Custom Structure`, not `Post name`, and insert `/%category%/%postname%/` there. The `Category base` under `Optional` is the base for *Category Archives*, not single posts.

Comment: The option page doesnt say so and it actually works so its kind of confusing :) , but your rule is right, it works properly even in editor :) the option page literaly says "If you like, you may enter custom structures for your category and tag URLs here. For example, using topics as your category base would make your category links like http://example.org/topics/uncategorized/. If you leave these blank the defaults will be used."